# How can I make multiple text based java menus work?

Tags: java, menu, switch-statement, text-based, system.in

I have a main menu for a movie kiosk, I can type a number (in this case 5) and it will take me to an admin menu. The problem is the admin menu has a different set of cases and when I enter a number to access a case from the admin menu it just takes me back to the main menu.

I am not sure what I could change in the code to make it work, I expected that when I enter a number in the admin menu, it will execute the method specified.

At the beginning I call the `use()` method from the `Kiosk` class
Which executes this menu:

When I press 2 it takes me to the main menu instead of executing `addCustomer()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to implement it like this:

```
while ((choice = readChoice()) != 'X') {
        switch (choice) {
        case '1': catalogue(); break;
        case '2': useAdmin(); break;
        }
    }

private void useAdmin() {
    char choice = admin(); // instead of assigning 5 to this option
        switch (choice) {
        case '1': listCustomer(); break;
        case '2': addCustomer(); break;
        case 'R': use();
    }
}
```

In your current implementation you call the `admin()` function which returns a char.

```
 switch (choice) {
        case '1': catalogue(); break;
        case '2': admin(); break;
        }
```

note that you don't do anything with the char the `admin()` function returns. Later on you just assign the character `5` to the `char choice`.

Comment: Great :). Good luck!